# span not changing class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some markup as shown below

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-addon-info">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="True" /></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="equitytrading" runat="server" CssClass="form-control bootstrap-default" text="Equity Trading" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-addon-info">
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="False"  /></span>
     <asp:TextBox ID="optionstrading" runat="server" CssClass="form-control  bootstrap-default" text="Options Trading" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-addon-info">
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="False"  /></span>
     <asp:TextBox ID="futurestrading" runat="server" CssClass="form-control  bootstrap-default" text="Futures Trading" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>                       
</div>
```

I am trying to change the background color of the span that holds the check box. when it is checked. Can't seem to get anything to work. Here is my latest attempt, which I really think should work since the span is the parent of the checkbox..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
           if ($(this).checked) {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info');
               $(this).parent().addClass('bootstrap-addon-success');
           }               
       });          
   });
```

**Update:**

The working version is as follows, thanks to those who replied for the help.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
        checkboxes.on('click',function() {
           //per chriz suggestion for chaining
           if (this.checked) {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info').addClass('bootstrap-addon-success');
           } else {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-success').addClass('bootstrap-addon-info');
           }
       });
        checkboxes.each(function () {
            //so on page load the checked ones that were set in the html had the success class
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('bootstrap-addon-info bootstrap-addon-success');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You syntax is incorrect. `$(this)` is a jQuery object it doesn't have checked property. So you can use `this.checked` or `$(this).prop('checked')`

Use

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
       $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info');
       $(this).parent().addClass('bootstrap-addon-success');
   }               
});
```

***OR***

You can simply use

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('bootstrap-addon-info bootstrap-addon-success');
});
```

EDIT:

You can also try

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('bootstrap-addon-info bootstrap-addon-success');
    else
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('bootstrap-addon-success bootstrap-addon-info');
}).change();
```

Comment: As i see it, could be: `$(this).parent().toggleClass('bootstrap-addon-info bootstrap-addon-success');` :)

Comment: You can also access the HTML element directly with `$(this).get(0)` or `$(this)[0]`.

Comment: @Boaz so just use `this` in that case

Comment: Thank you, dumb error on my part. And I used the toggleClass as AWolff reminded me to but the color is not changing back when check box is unchecked

Comment: @A.Wolff True. Stated it as an option for future readers. Do note however that this claim is not limited to `$(this)` of course. See [You might not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `.each` on all checkboxes. Try to get checkboxes which are `checked` so that u wont even need to use if

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {

           $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info');
           $(this).parent().addClass('bootstrap-addon-success');

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

a little simpler way

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
           $(this).parent().addClass('bootstrap-addon-succes').removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info');               
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead $(this)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
           if (this.checked) {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('bootstrap-addon-info');
               $(this).parent().addClass('bootstrap-addon-success');
           }               
       });          
   });
```